# Problem: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endwith'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
@app.route("/user")
def user():
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return render_template("user.html", user=user)
    else:
        flash("You are not logged in")
        return redirect(url_for("login")
```

This is the python code and below is the html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} User {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
                <p>{{msg}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
<p>Welcome, {{user}} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Problem: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endwith' ...and i cannot figure out what is the problem. Im pretty sure its something obvious.

Debugger shows me two problems: first in python codefile and the second in the user.html file.

And here is the traceback:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHjrS.png)

Comment: What version of jinja are you using? You can check the package versions by running "pip freeze" on the terminal. You mentioned "Debugger shows me two problems: first in python codefile and the second in the user.html file." Could you add the stack trace to your OP

Comment: are you sure there is no space between `{` and `%` in any tag?

Comment: @AkibRhast my current version of jinja is Jinja2==2.11.2

Comment: Hmm, so version isn't the  issue please add the stack trace to your OP

Comment: @moeassal i checked and didnt find any spaces.

Comment: I dont see this "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:" in your stack trace? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AkibRhast how about now?

Comment: Try commenting out and deleting this line `<p>Welcome, {{user}} </p>`  , does the error still occur?

Comment: @AkibRhast i tried deleting the line <p>Welcome, {{user}} </p> but it didn't fix the error.

Comment: Okay i solved this, it was just a parsing problem. Carry on, nothing to see here.